# Is $P(A \cap B) \leq P(A)P(B)$?

Tags: probability

I'm looking to understand whether the following inequality holds true:

$$
P(A \cap B) \leq P(A)P(B)
$$

I would appreciate a formal proof or a counterexample to demonstrate whether this inequality is generally true or not. If possible, please provide an explanation along with the mathematical proof.

Thank you!

Comment: Try $A\cap B = A \subsetneq B \neq \Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional probability, you have $P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)P(B)$ but also $P(A\cap B)=P(B|A)P(A)$.

This leads to $$ P(A\cap B)^2=P(A|B)\cdot P(B|A)\cdot P(A)\cdot P(B)$$ so that is becomes clear by the axioms of probability that
$$
P(A\cap B)^2\leq P(A)\cdot P(B).
$$
Thus, $P(A\cap B)\leq\sqrt{P(A)\cdot P(B)}$.

Comment: Your conclusion is not the inequality of OP. It is weaker since generically $\sqrt{A}>A$ for $A \in [0,1].$ did you see the comment of Benjamin Wang which is a counterexample to the inequality of OP?

Comment: Dear @coffeemath. I saw the comment. Of course, the inequality $P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)\cdot P(B)$ does not hold, in general.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample:

Consider the equiprobable sample space: $\Omega=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and the events:
$A=\{a,b,c\}$, $B=\{a,c\}$,
Note that: $P(A)=\frac{3}{4}$ and $P(B)=\frac{1}{2}$, but:
$P(A\cap B)=P(B)=\frac{1}{2}>\frac{3}{8}=P(A)P(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Although the proposed relation does not always hold, the following relation is always valid:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\varnothing \subseteq A\cap B\subseteq A\\\\
\varnothing \subseteq A\cap B\subseteq B
\end{cases} & \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
0\leq \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \leq \mathbb{P}(A)\\\\
0\leq \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \leq \mathbb{P}(B)
\end{cases} \tag{Monotonicity of $\mathbb{P}$}\\\\
& \Rightarrow [\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)]^{2} \leq \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)\\\\
& \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\leq\sqrt{\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)}
\end{align*}